# Delete Directory Even On File Use

Tags: java, c#

When trying to delete Directory using Directory.Delete(path,true)

If i have a file opened from that Directory. I cannot delete that Directory.

Is any other way we can delete Directory, Even any of the file from that Directory is open.

Comment: I'm not aware of any OS that would allow it.

Comment: You would need to close the file first before deleting the directory. If it is a file running on the same machine then you could terminate the process. If other computers have access to that folder then it would be more difficult.

Comment: How do you expect that to ever work, on any O/S? Think about it - if you delete the folder, yet the file is still open, and the application in control of the file tries to save the file, or worse, re-load it...what should happen? The user editing the file would be pretty annoyed, too. I don't think it's a logical thing to want.

Comment: On my reasearch i also found that, it's not possible to delete the directory without closing also the files opened

Answer (score 0):

Such operation can't be done. It is restricted by operating system.
It's not only about security reasons but the way we access different objects in OS.

Either terminate the corresponding process or close the file before deleting directory.

You can try using [unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/)

I'm not sure if it can be scripted, though.

Alternative will be [FileAssassin](https://www.malwarebytes.com/fileassassin/). It does support command-line usage, so you should be able to script it. So potentially you'll be able to close opened files in particular directory programatically